# Unable to create bitmap from Path

Tags: android, bitmap, uri, android-glide, android-bitmap

My code is not creating bitmap from path i have searched alot but found no solution here is my code

```
val bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path)
```

it always return null i have also try glide to do this but nothing works

```
  Glide.with(requireActivity()).asBitmap().load(pictureFilePath)
            .apply(RequestOptions().override(50, 50))
            .listener(object  : RequestListener<Bitmap> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Bitmap>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(bitmap: Bitmap, model: Any?, target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Bitmap>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    val mybitmap= bitmap // this bitmap return null

                    return true
                }

            }).submit()
```

anyone who can help me in this little thing? i am so tired of doing this

Comment: Where did `path` come from?

Comment: @CommonsWare from camera i got uri then convert it into real path

Comment: One does not get uries from camera. One offers camera an uri so the camera app can write a picture to it.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have check path is correct but when i create bitmap it returns bitmap null

Comment: "from camera i got uri then convert it into real path" -- as blackapps notes, you do not get a `Uri` from the camera. And, generally speaking, a `Uri` does not have a "real path". You might want to edit this question, or ask a new one, where you provide a [mcve] that shows all the steps you take that result in this `path` value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, path is your local path please make sure that your path is correct

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight(),true);
```